# Counting cycles on Cortex M0+

Tags: arduino, cycle, cortex-m

I have a Cortex M0+ (SAML21) board that I'm using for performance testing. I'd like to measure how many cycles a given piece of code takes. I tried using DWT (`DWT_CONTROL`), but it never produced a result; it returned 0 cycles regardless of what code ran.

```
  // enable the use DWT
  *DEMCR = *DEMCR | 0x01000000;

  // Reset cycle counter
  *DWT_CYCCNT = 0;

  // enable cycle counter
  *DWT_CONTROL = *DWT_CONTROL | 1 ;
  // some code here
  // .....

  // number of cycles stored in count variable
  count = *DWT_CYCCNT;
```

Is there a way to count cycles (perhaps with an interrupt and counter?) much like I can query for milliseconds (eg. `millis()` on Arduino)?

Comment: this processor doesnt necessarily work that way, if the chip vendor (atmel now microchip) does not do any flash caching (like st) then you can time some code at a specific address with specific settings and get a count.  but move that code to another alignment, change the clock settings, etc  and the number of cpu clocks for that code can change a little or a lot.

Comment: The cycle counter is an optional feature on the M0+. Are you sure this implementation actually has the feature?

Comment: @RealtimeRik, I am not sure. I'm dealing with the ATSAML21E18B, which dues have debug capabilities. But, I think andy mango is correct; I have to read those registers out via JTAG.

Comment: Possibly. I am not sure without looking it up. I know on a M3/M4 you can read the cycle counter programatically as I have used it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find any mention of the cycle counter register in the [ARMv6-M Architecture Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0419/e/?lang=en).

So I'd say, this is not possible with an internal counter like it is in the bigger siblings like the [M3](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0337/e/System-Debug/DWT), M4 and so on.

This is also stated in [this](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka001499/latest) knowledge base article:

> This article was written for Cortex-M3 and Cortex-M4, but the same points apply to Cortex-M7, Cortex-M33 and Cortex-M55. Newer Cortex-M processors at the higher end of performance, such as Cortex-M55, may include an extended Performance Motnioring Unit that provides additional preformance measuring capabilities, but these are outside the scope of this article. **The smaller Cortex-M processors such as **Cortex-M0, Cortex-M0+ and Cortex-M23** do not include the DWT capabilities described here**, and, other than the Cortex-M23, do not include ETM instruction trace, but all Cortex-M processors provide the "tarmac" capability for the chip designers.

(Emphasis mine)

So other means have to be used:

- some debuggers can measure the time between hitting two breakpoints (or between two stops), the accuracy of this is usually limited by interacting with the OS, so can easily be in the order of 20 ms
- use an internal timer with high enough clock frequency to give reasonable results and start / stop it before and after the interesting region
- toggle a pin and measure the time with a logic analyzer / oscilloscope

Answer (score 1):

According to the CMSIS header file for the M0+ (core_cm0plus.h), the Core Debug Registers are only accessible over the Debug Access Port and not via the processor. I can only suggest using some free running timer (maybe SysTick) or perhaps your debugger can be of some help to get access to the required registers.